# Can buildbot be forced to run a build on multiple nodes?

Tags: buildbot

I have a project that I want to build on multiple nodes (several different architectures and operating systems). I then want to create packages on each node (debs and RPMs). Because of the different architectures and operating systems, I want buildbot to schedule a build for this project on several nodes at the same time.

Can that be done? What's the best way? Creating separate builders for each operating system / architecture combination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So yes, this is possible, but not in the way I thought it would be.

In order to make buildbot run a build on multiple nodes (in my case, to generate RPMs and Debs), you create multiple groups of workers, and a schedulers that lists all these groups as buildernames.

You then create a BuildFactory that builds your artifacts, and finally you create multiple BuilderConfigs that map that factory to your workers.

I hope that, if you read this, looking for an answer, you will find this useful.

Feel free to pring this question for a couple of config snippets.